# MYSQL : Unique Message Threads

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a messages table with columns like

> message_id, message_to_id, message_from_id, message_body, project_id.

I want a list of message threads for a particular user. 
Message thread should have a unique combination of fields message_to_id, message_from_id and project_id.

Earlier I was using group by on project_id but I don't want to make them group message over project.

```
SELECT * FROM message
WHERE message_to = '{$user_id}' OR message_from = '{$user_id}'
GROUP BY project
```

This didn't work as expected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE message_to = '{$user_id}' 
GROUP BY message_from 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE message_from = '{$user_id}' 
GROUP BY message_to
```

This is showing me combinations of message_from and message_to which I don't want.

I want a message thread per user combination on a single project.

> Sample Data

```
message_id | message_from_id | message_to_id | project_id | message _body
1          |  283            |  284          | 4          | Hello         
2          |  284            |  283          | 4          | Hi            
3          |  285            |  283          | 4          | Hey there!    
4          |  283            |  285          | 4          | Greetings     
5          |  283            |  284          | 6          | Cool!
```

> What I want

```
message_id | message_from_id | message_to_id | project_id | message _body 
1          |  283            |  284          | 4          | Hello                
3          |  285            |  283          | 4          | Hey there!  
5          |  283            |  284          | 6          | Cool!
```

i.e ignore message_from_id and message_to_id ordering but together with project_id they should be unique.

Comment: can you please edit your question with sample data and desired output .That will make your question relevant and easy to understand requirement

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, I have added sample data as you requested.

Comment: Thanks @Blag for editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a completely different solutions using an `ON` or ranking approach (`ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`) although this wasn't compatible with all SQL versions, looking around I found a `JOIN` approach that appears to do the job.

Here is my result:

```
SELECT message.message_id, message_to_id, message.message_from_id, message.project_id, message.message_body FROM 
  message
INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT MIN(message_id) message_idMIN FROM message WHERE message_to_id = 283 GROUP BY project_id, message_to_id
    UNION 
  SELECT MIN(message_id) message_idMIN FROM message WHERE message_from_id = 283 GROUP BY project_id, message_from_id
  ) message_group
ON message.message_id = message_group.message_idMIN;
```

See the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef36a1/32

Comment: Thank you so much, but somehow I am getting incorrect result with actual data. It is giving me the same to_id and from_id pair.

Comment: Is it possible for a user to send a message to themselves? If you can reproduce this with actual (anonymised) data and post back then I can investigate further

Comment: No, a user cannot send a message to themselves. Also, I cannot send any other dataset . This is the only one I can provide . Please create your own examples if needed.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation right now so I can't upvote you. But thank you so much for trying to fix this problem.

Comment: Andy, for future reference the query I sent over works on the data provided. If I was to invent a dataset that then satisfied the conditions you report there would be no guarantee that this is the same issue on your side, cue chasing tails etc. As the OP you should be prepared to provide sample data if the issue is to be resolved. (Saying that as helpful advice for future reference). Regards

Comment: As your data works on current sample data. I am marking your answer as the right answer. Sorry If I have offended you in any way. I will deal the problem at my end. But I cannot provide any more data. Thank you for answering =)

Comment: Hi Andy, no, no offence taken at all, thank you for marking the answer correct. As you're new on the site I just wanted to give you a heads-up on the way people like to do things around here to help you get the most from the site in the future - welcome!

Comment: I just hope people like you exist even more. That will definitely make this world a better place.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to ignore the combination of message_to and message_from and give distinct of the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN message_from_id < message_to_id 
    THEN message_from_id 
    ELSE message_to_id END as message_from_id, 
    CASE WHEN message_from_id < message_to_id 
    THEN message_to_id 
    ELSE message_from_id END as message_to_id, 
    project 
FROM message 
WHERE message_to_id = '{$user_id}' OR message_from_id = '{$user_id}'
```

This way it can work without Group By Clause.

But the problem with this solution is I can't get any non-distinct columns like sent_at (which I didn't mention here).